# jquery - basic for loop issue

Tags: jquery, html

I want to update the src of an image depending on a link that I click with jquery. I have four links and an image displayed above.

If I click on the first link, I want the src of the image to change of the first element of the container array. It should increment like that until reaching the last element of the array.

What is the best way to do this basic approach?

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" />
    <figcaption>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Image One</a>
            <a href="#">Image Two</a>
            <a href="#">Image Three</a>
            <a href="#">Image Four</a>
        </nav>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){

    var container = [
       "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
       "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"
    ];

    var i;
    $("nav a").on("click", function(){
            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                $("img").attr("src", container[i]);
            }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var container = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/"];

$("nav a").on("click", function () {
    $("img").prop("src", container[$(this).index()]);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LVaEk/1/)**

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function to find which link was clicked on and select the corresponding array element. Both are zero-based.

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to use `prop()` or can I also use `attr()`?

Comment: That depends on the version of jQuery you're using. With the latest versions use prop().

Comment: @Tantra - Did something not work? I see you've unaccepted my answer.